# Writing text based on subscription from MQTT

Tags: react-native, mqtt

So I have an app that recieves messages from a Raspberry Pi. It all works great, but I have no idea how I would actually output the text based on the topic it is subscribed to. Right now I get all the topics printed one next to the other whenever a state changes. The text also does not dissapear whenever a new state on that specific topic comes, they just kind of awkwardly mesh into one big string. Any help would be appreciated.
This is the client part with the subscriptions:

```
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this)
    this.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost.bind(this)


    const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('broker.hivemq.com', 8000, 'pi@njolac');
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.connect({ 
      onSuccess: this.onConnect,
      useSSL: false ,
      onFailure: (e) => {console.log("here is the error" , e); }

    });

    this.state = {
      message: [''],
      client,
      messageToSend:'',
      isConnected: false,
    };

  }


  onMessageArrived(entry) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived:"+entry.payloadString);
    this.setState({message: [...this.state.message, entry.payloadString]});

  }


  onConnect = () => {
    const { client } = this.state;
    console.log("Connected!!!!");
    client.subscribe('Temperatura');
    client.subscribe('Vlaga');
    client.subscribe('Motor')
    this.setState({isConnected: true, error: ''})
  };
```

This is the text output:

```
<Text style={styles.instructions}>
   Message: {this.state.message}
</Text>
```

Any help would mean a lot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure quite where the topic is stored in the `entry` object with this client. I recommend you `console.log(entry)` and look at the printed object to work out where the topic is stored; it may be `entry.destinationName` or `entry.topic`.

Your messages are concatenating because you're storing an array of messages, and appending every new message to this. Then in your output you're writing the entire array to the screen. Either only store the latest message, or only display the last element of the array.

The below code is for illustration, it hasn't been debugged/tested:

If you want to display the latest message from each topic you may be better storing messages in a dictionary:

```
messageByTopic = {
    'Temperatura': 'temperaturaMessage',
    'Vlaga': 'vlagaMessage'
}
```

Then in your output, for each topic (key in the dictionary), write the latest message:

```
<div>
{Object.keys(this.state.messageByTopic).map((topic) => {
    return (
      <h4>Topic: </h4> {topic}
      <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Message: {this.state.messageByTopic[topic]}
      </Text>)
})
</div>
```

**Edit**

```
onMessageArrived(entry) {

    this.setState((state) => ({
        ...state.items,
        messageByTopic: {
            ...state.messageByTopic,
            `${entry.destinationName}`: entry.payloadString
         }
     }));

}
```

Comment: After checking it loos like this:
INFO
15:56
onMessageArrived:Zemlja je vlazna
INFO
15:56
Array [
  "",
  "22.312",
  "Zemlja je vlazna",
  "22.312",
  "Zemlja je vlazna",
]
INFO
16:00

I don't really get any concrete info about it...

Also, should have mentioned, this is for react native :D

Comment: @Njolac That looks like your message array. Your `entry.payloadString` contains "Zemlja je vlazna" and `this.state.messages` contains [ "", "22.312", "Zemlja je vlazna", "22.312", "Zemlja je vlazna", ]. You are just appending data to the messages array - to just see the latest message you should `this.setState({message: [entry.payloadString]})`. But I'm guessing you want to store the latest message for each topic which will require a dictionary. Could you `console.log(entry)` so we can better understand the entry object. This should give us clues as to which topic a message is coming from.

Comment: @Njolac In terms of how you should store the messages, take a look at this example. It should work in the same way to your code, except a `<TextInput />` and a `<Button />`are used to submit new messages rather than a socket connection. https://codesandbox.io/s/reactnativemessages-q5bgx. This demonstrates how a dictionary should be used and updated to store the latest message by topic. If you can log the `entry` object for me then I'll be able to take a look at your other query. If I've missed the point with your application then let me know!

Comment: That's exactly how I envisioned the app. I'll try to implement it and post the results.  
Here is the entry object:
Object {
  "_getDestinationName": [Function anonymous],  
  "_getDuplicate": [Function anonymous],  
  "_getPayloadBytes": [Function anonymous],  
  "_getPayloadString": [Function anonymous],  
  "_getQos": [Function anonymous],  
  "_getRetained": [Function anonymous],  
  "_setDestinationName": [Function anonymous],  
  "_setDuplicate": [Function anonymous],  
  "_setQos": [Function anonymous],  
  "_setRetained": [Function anonymous],  
}

Comment: @Njolac I think the end of the object has been cut off by the character limit. Would you mind pasting it into https://pastebin.com/, click `Create New Paste`, and share the link with me?

Comment: @Njolac Thank you. Not what I expected unfortunately. My guess is that entry.destinationName will contain the topic name. If not then I’m not sure sorry!

Comment: entry.destinationName returns the topic name! I tryed to console log entry.Vlaga but it comes out as undefined. What's the proper way to do this now?

Comment: @Njolac I’ve added an edit to the bottom of my answer. Just update the relevant dictionary entry with the new message based on the topic. Best of luck with it! If that’s everything would you mind marking my answer as solving the question?